# How to load changes instantly - React Native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, react-native

## Question

How do I load new data every time it is added to the server?

## What I would like to have happen

- User opens app
- User uploads text to server
- The app displays the text from the server immediately

## What is currently happening

- Users uploads text to server
- User reloads app
- The app displays the text from the server

## Server Side

I am using expressJS for the server and then I am saving all of the text that the server gets to an off-site mongoose DB.

## More info

- I am using a Node JS server
- I am using the fetch API to communicate between the server and the
  client
- The client app is **written with React Native**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your app makes requests. Some code from both server and client would be useful. But i can think two possible solutions for your situation:

**Return your text from upload request**

Since you need server's response `AFTER` user uploads text to server, you can use `response data` within `upload request`. Here is an example code:

```
fetch('https://your-server.com/api/upload-text/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    text: 'yourValue',
  })
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(responseJson => {
  // Here is your text returned from server
  let serverText = responseJson.text

  // Set your state here with new data
  this.setState({
    textFromServer: serverText
  });
  // Now you can display new data in your render method.
})
```

With this way, users do not need to reload the app to fetch new text data. Your app will be updated after server responds to upload request.

**WebSocket**

If the data that you need from server is not depends on a client request, you can use `websockets`. With this way, you can fetch / send any data from server or from other clients any time. `React Native` supports `websockets`. More on [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket-support)

Comment: Thank you, but I am wondering how I make the app always listening, I would like it to fetch the new data everytime it's updated. Even if that use is not the one that updates it.

Comment: That's why i mentioned websockets. Use websockets and send a message to client everytime data is updated. That is why websockets stand for.

Comment: Just check `socket.io` examples to see how to communicate between server and client. it is pretty simple. @pudility

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering if there is any way to do this without bothering the server to much. I imagine if every time a request is made, the server has to evaluate who to tell to refresh and then tell them to refresh, it would be very resource heavy. I am wondering if there is a way to do this where the client is the one updating, and not the server. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the server has tents two hundreds of requests a second, this could be an issue. Is there any other way make it more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: `the server has to evaluate who to tell to refresh and then tell them to refresh` this would be one request. Then client will refresh the app, this will be second request. Two requests for one job. This is not efficient. Websockets are more handy for your situation. @pudility